# How to get missing fields from cybersource reply using SOAP toolkit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, payment-processing

Im working with Cybersource SOAP toolkit API. I'm getting response as "Required fields missing" for my transaction request . How can I get the names of missing fields from Cybersource reply? I know there is a array of strings named 'missingFiled'. But missingFields[0] gives me value 'c:item[0]'.